# Get sum of items by date in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a shop model with products in it, and I have a sales model, like this:

```
sale_product_name = models.CharField()
sale_product_price = models.IntegerField()
sale_date = models.DateField()
```

Now for the statistics I want to get sums of the sales by date (month to date)

So it look like this:

Lets say that today is 15 November 2016

```
01.11 - 500.00 $ | 02.11 - 150.00 $ | and so on...
```

with template code like this

```
{% for dayly_summ in dayly_summs %}
    {{ dayly_summ.date }} {{dayly_summ.summ))
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

result = Model.objects.values('sale_date').annotate(sale_date_sum=Sum('sale_product_price')).order_by()
```

Comment: It's very close, but it's not grouping summ values by date: so I have /Oct. 16, 2016, 5:53 a.m.: 1,840
Oct. 16, 2016, 5:14 a.m.: 7,500
Oct. 16, 2016, 5:56 a.m.: 10
Oct. 16, 2016, 6:17 a.m.: 15,000/

But it must be - Oct. 16, 2016 24,350